# Android "home"-application locks Nexus S at boot

Tags: android, startup, boot, homescreen, kiosk

I have developed an application that runs in a "Kiosk"-mode by presenting itself as a home application.

This application runs on several (50 devices, Nexus S) and is distributed alongside android market.
The application also catches the "OnBoot" to complete the Kiosk-illusion.

**The problem:**
Sometimes as the device boots it gets stuck in the boot animation with the animated X, and the  support team have so far done a manual Factory Reset, and reinstalled the application.
The largest problem I have is that I dont know how to reproduce the error, and thus cannot troubleshoot.

- In what circumstances could this occur?
- The application tries to connect to my server at boot, perhaps before android gets a 3G-lock? Could this cause the lockup? And if so could it be solved with a simple delay of starting the services?
- What shouldn't you do at boot? Best practice etc?

Thankful for help!
 I will try to answer all questions!

Edit--
The problem is reoccuring, it is not a sporadic incident but instead once it has happened it will happen on every boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by delaying all tasks until user clicked a button "ready to start".